# Extracting content from OneNote to Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2, onenote

i need to know if there is any way possible for me to extract content in a OneNote notebook/section to a sql server database.
basically what i need to do is.. read the content from OneNote and insert it to a sql server table.
i am using OneNote 2010 and Sql server 2008 R2. 
thank you. 
:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OneNote COM API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff925947%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to read contents of OneNote notebooks. The format is XML. Once you read the contents, you need to manually convert it to a format that can be used to insert into the SQL Server table.